# Error in backend: Failed to load plugin: tabfocus from url

Tags: tinymce, editor, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I'm getting an error that looks really wierd (notice the red error, running all the way down from top to bottom, over the left sidebar):

[image: Failed to load plugin: wordPress from url]

The error is:

> Failed to load plugin: wordPress from url http://example.local/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wordpress/plugin.min.js

But I got an error earlier today, appeared in the same wierd fashion, but the error was then:

> Error in backend: Failed to load plugin: tabfocus from url url http://example.local/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wordpress/plugin.min.js

The error comes and goes, - and I'm unable to figure out, why it appears. When it appeared earlier today, then I deactivated all plugins; and then the error disappeared. Then I reactivated all my plugins, - and the error was still gone!?

I just tried doing the same thing just now, but this time it didn't solve it.

My original theory is, that it's either because of:

- [Yoast](https://yoast.com/)
- [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)
- Or because I'm running on a local environment, using [Flywheel](https://getflywheel.com/)

But I don't think so anymore, since the error comes and goes, - and that it persists, even after reactivating the plugins again.

As can be seen on above-shown image, then I've deactivated the editor. I'm doing that with these lines:

```php
/**
 * Disable regular editor
 */
function custom_init_remove_support(){
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor');
    remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_init_remove_support', 100 );
```

Could that maybe somehow be related to the error?

Comment: I believe this error is related to some ad-blocker plugins in combo with your browser. I'm getting an error in a couple of my systems which appears the same way, but I think has something to do with advanced ads and ablock plus (chrome). As I've said, I'm not sure, but maybe worth investigating. My error disappears when I deactivate advanced ads. Maybe Yoast is producing the same type of error. cheers.

Comment: Uhh!! That's a good theory. I'll try and disable ad-block on my dev-site, the next time it appears (it's gone now).

Comment: Thanks :) - I'm curious about the result, please let me know.